# Change default Windows Explorer behavior when opening new windows (cascade)

Tags: windows, windows-10, task-manager, window-manager

Whenever I spawn a new window, MS Windows (explorer.exe) opens it **in cascade** by default. Is there a setting to change this behavior to open in the **same position as the parent window**?

## ***Example 1.*** *When SHIFT+CLICK a link in a browser:*

[image]

[image]

## ***Example 2.*** *When CTRL+N or "File -> New Window" in file Explorer:*

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Hunter SHIFT+CLICK opens a new window, CTRL+CLICK opens a new tab. At least in Chrome for Windows. See the attached screenshots

Comment: My question has nothing to do with any specific application like Google Chrome. It's about the way MS Windows do "window management"

Comment: @Hunter Window placement is part of OS's window management, it's not software specific

Comment: Man, you're completely out of context, you're not interpreting this question properly. This is what I am talking about:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969540(v=vs.85).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh848042(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I think that you are mistaken what DWM is, I am not out of context, rather your question is wrong as DWM is rather a graphical enhancement, which allows transparency and other display effects. It doesn't do what you are trying to do. You have it already wrong and should check first the links what you posted and understand what they mean and do. And it's not a window manager but it's windows os manager, it just offers graphical enhancements to the windows desktops, like the 3d flip in windows 7.

Comment: Fair enough, but as I pointed Windows Explorer (explorer.exe) acts as a window manager: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager#Microsoft_Windows

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26719/discussion-between-benoror-and-hunter).

Comment: Man, windows explorer is not a windows manager but a file explorer, you should read your posts correctly. And what does DWM i.e. desktop window manager does to a file explorer manager is that when you open a new window it opens in a tiling effect, like in the above picture you posted. Just try to open more instances of it and see yourself. Was a great type of prank virus I used to do in my computer lab. You should read first before posting.

Answer (score 0):

You're showing an internet browser in the first two graphics.  That is NOT Windows Exlorer.  Responders are not understanding your question, but you have not made it straight-forward with the extraneous graphics.  The second two graphics clearly show the issue that you are describing.  I get it and would also like to change this, however, I don't think it's possible without recompiling explorer.exe, which you can't (and wouldn't want to) do, generally.

Also, it would be cool to avoid political content.  This just isn't the place.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).